# Deduce types pack from a variadic-templated class and declare an argument of the same types pack

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

First off, sorry for unclear question title, feel free to edit if you think of a better way to state it.

I have a class:

```
template <typename ...Arguments>
class CSignal
{
    template <typename ...ActualArguments>
    void invoke(ActualArguments&&... args) const {}
};
```

And another one, this is what I have a problem with:

```
class SomeClass
{
    template<typename ...Arguments>
    void invokeQueued(CSignal<Arguments...>& signal, const Arguments&... args)
    {
        m_queue.emplace_back([=](){signal.invoke(args...);});
    }

    std::deque<std::function<void (void)>> m_queue;
};
```

Problem:

```
CSignal<float> signal;
int i = 0;
SomeClass().invokeQueued(signal, i);
```

Error:

```
template parameter 'Arguments' is ambiguous
could be 'float'
or       'int'
```

Possible naive solution

```
template<typename ...FormalArguments, typename ...ActualArguments>
void invokeQueued(CSignal<FormalArguments...>& signal, const ActualArguments&... args)
{
    m_queue.emplace_back([=](){signal.invoke(args...);});
}
```

is not acceptable in this specific case, because I **need** to capture the arguments by value (copy them into the lambda), and the conversion from `ActualArguments` to `FormalArguments` **must** occur at the time `invokeQueued` is called, not when the lambda is called.

If I could `typedef` the arguments pack in the `CSignal` class, I would do:

```
template<typename ...FormalArguments>
void invokeQueued(CSignal<FormalArguments...>& signal, const CSignal<FormalArguments...>::argument_types&... args)
{
    m_queue.emplace_back([=](){signal.invoke(args...);});
}
```

But it doesn't seem possible. Solutions?

Comment: Why must it happen when `invokeQueue` is called?

Comment: @Barry: because the functor will be saved and called later, by which time the original arguments will be long gone out of scope. Example: `CSignal<std::string> signal; SomeClass().invokeQueued(signal, "123")`. Conversion from `const char[4]` to `std::string` exists and it must occur right now, while the `char*` pointer is valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you encounter is raised because the types of arguments differ while a compiler has only one type template parameter for each such a pair: from the `CSignal`'s signature it sees `float`, while from the deduced type of the second argument it sees `int`, and both have to be matched against a single element of the `Arguments` pack. This is where the ambiguity originates from.

To work around that, you can exclude one of the parameters from template argument deduction by introducing a *non-deduced context*, like with the below *identity* trick:

```
template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };
template <typename T> using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;

class SomeClass
{
public:
    template <typename... Arguments>
    void invokeQueued(CSignal<Arguments...>& signal,
                      const identity_t<Arguments>&... args)
    //                      ~~~~~~~~~^
    {
        m_queue.emplace_back([=](){signal.invoke(args...);});
    }

    std::deque<std::function<void(void)>> m_queue;
};
```

The compiler will not attempt to deduce any template parameter that is part of *nested name specifier* syntax, and this is basically what `identity` does - it introduces the `identity<T>::type` syntax, so that `T` is left to a scope resolution operator, yet it still can be used intact in the function declaration.

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7cfebc4e29fdcf9)

---

Alternatively, you may store decayed copies of arguments converted to proper types at the time of capturing them in a lambda expression (C++14):

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

class SomeClass
{
public:
    template <typename... FormalArguments, typename... ActualArguments>
    void invokeQueued(CSignal<FormalArguments...>& signal, ActualArguments&&... args)
    {
        invokeQueued(signal, std::index_sequence_for<ActualArguments...>{}, std::forward<ActualArguments>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename... FormalArguments, typename... ActualArguments, std::size_t... Is>
    void invokeQueued(CSignal<FormalArguments...>& signal, std::index_sequence<Is...>, ActualArguments&&... args)
    {
        m_queue.emplace_back(
          [signal, t = std::tuple<std::decay_t<FormalArguments>...>(std::forward<ActualArguments>(args)...)]
          (){signal.invoke(std::get<Is>(t)...);});
    }

    std::deque<std::function<void(void)>> m_queue;
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f6764b5ab472d98)

Comment: That works! At least it compiles, hopefully it does copy the arguments, will check that later. I don't have a slightest understanding of the `using` syntax, though :(

Comment: Convention is to reverse the roles of `identity` and `identity_t`, as the standard uses the `_t`-extension for the version which does not need the `typename `something`::type`.

Comment: @DanielFrey yes it is, but I like the opposite approach

Comment: @PiotrS FWIW, I feel the same.

Comment: The `identity_t` struct also seems to work with `typedef T type` instead of `using type = T`. Is there any difference between the two declarations in this context?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe no difference between those two. Also that identity alias for identity_t is just for convenience.

Comment: @PiotrS.: I think I get it now, thank you. It's just a way to create a usable alias for otherwise inaccessible `Arguments` type. And `identity` is as close as we can get to a templated `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity trick to create a [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) for `Arguments&&...`.

```
template <typename T>
class Identity
{
public:
using type = T;
};

template<typename ...Arguments>
void invokeQueued(CSignal<Arguments...>& signal, const typename Identity<Arguments>::type &... args)
{
    m_queue.emplace_back([=](){signal.invoke(args...);});
}
```